# VLC VLM non-streaming output

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player

I've been looking at VLM, and I really like the schedule feature. I just need the option for a non-streaming output: OpenGL, DX3D, X11, SDL... as long as it can go onto the local console, I'll be happy. Is this possible? I was thinking maybe it'd just be the appropriate string instead of a streaming specifier, but I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of a normal streaming specifier:

```
:sout=#display
```

Comment: that works perfectly! now, would you be so kind as to link to the description of these specifiers? I found a few examples, but no full spec.

Comment: I find that the easiest way to figure these things out is to use the HTTP control interface.  Just add *--extraintf http --http-host 127.0.0.1:8080* to the VLC command line and browse to http://localhost:8080/vlm.html and you can build complex VLM commands with a graphical tool and it will display the command and/or just do it.  That's how I figured that one out quickly.